# How could I solve this system of equations with 3 variables, and others with more variables?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

6=a+b+c

11=a*b+(a+b)*c

6=a*b*c

And other ones with more variables such as

10=a+b+c+d

35=a*b+(a+b)*c+(a+b+c)*d

50=(a*b*c)+d((a*b)(a+b)*c)

24=a*b*c*d*

So that I can get the roots of higher degree polynomials without having to approximate.

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $a, b, c$? For example, we have the cyclic solution $\{1, 2, 3\}$ for the first.

Comment: Nope, the solution you provided was right for the first one. Just need a good method that I can use for these system of equations, that isn't going to be hindered too much when I add more variables, so I can solve higher degree polynomials much easier than the methods I'm currently learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roots of $$ x^3 - 6 x^2 + 11x-6,  $$
$$ x^4 - 10x^3 + 35 x^2 - 50 x + 24. $$
Which seem to be $(1,2,3)$ and $(1,2,3,4)$

[SEE VIETE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas#Basic_formulas)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind adding how you got the answers, and the method you used, I would really appreciate it. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.